# JavaScript Node.js WebScraping: How do I find specific elements on webpage table to scrape and push into an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, web-scraping

I am trying to practice web scraping using a betting site for UFC fights.  I am using javascript and the packages request-promise and cheerio.

Site: https://www.oddsshark.com/ufc/odds

I want to scrape the name of the fighters and their respective betting lines for each betting company.

[image: sample screen shot of website]

My goal is to end up with something like an array of objects that I can later seed a postgresql database with.

Example of my desired output (doesn't have to be exactly like that but similar):

```
[
  { fighter 1: 'Khabib Nurmagomedov', openingBetLine: -333, bovadaBetLine: -365, etc. },
  { fighter 2: 'Dustin Poirier', openingBetLine: 225, bovadaBetLine: 275, etc. },
  { fighter 3: etc.},
  { fighter 4: etc.}
]
```

Below is the code I have so far.  I am a noob at this:

```
const rp = require("request-promise");
const url = "https://www.oddsshark.com/ufc/odds";


// cheerio to parse HTML
const $ = require("cheerio");

rp(url)
  .then(function(html) {
    // it worked :)

    // console.log("MMA page:", html);
    // console.log($("big > a", html).length);
    // console.log($("big > a", html));

    console.log($(".op-matchup-team-text", html).length);
    console.log($(".op-matchup-team-text", html));
  })
  // why isn't catch working?
  .catch(function(error) {
    // handle error
  });
```

My code above returns indexes as keys with nested objects as values.  Below is just one of them as an example.

```
{ '0':
   { type: 'tag',
     name: 'span',
     namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
     attribs: [Object: null prototype] { class: 'op-matchup-team-text' },
     'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] { class: undefined },
     'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] { class: undefined },
     children: [ [Object] ],
     parent:
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'div',
        namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        attribs: [Object],
        'x-attribsNamespace': [Object],
        'x-attribsPrefix': [Object],
        children: [Array],
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        next: [Object] },
     prev: null,
     next: null },
```

I don't know what to do from here.  Am I calling the right class (op-matchup-team-text)?  If so, how do I extract the fighter names and betting line tag elements from the website?

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
**UPDATE 1 ON ORIGINAL POST** //////////////////////////

Updated: Using Henk's suggestion, I'm able to scrape fighter name.  Using the code template for fighter name, I was able to scrape fighter betting lines as well.

*BUT I don't know how to get both on one object.  For example, how do I associate the betting line with the fighter him/herself?*

Below is my code for scraping the OPENING company's betting line:

```
rp(url)
  .then(function(html) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    const openingBettingLine = [];

    // parent class of fighter name
    $("div.op-item.op-spread.op-opening").each((index, currentDiv) => {
      const openingBet = {
        opening: JSON.parse(currentDiv.attribs["data-op-moneyline"]).fullgame
      };
      openingBettingLine.push(openingBet);
    });
    console.log("openingBettingLine array test 2:", openingBettingLine);
  })
  // why isn't catch working?
  // eslint-disable-next-line handle-callback-err
  .catch(function(error) {
    // handle error
  });
```

It console logs out the following:

```
openingBettingLine array test 2: [ { opening: '-200' },
  { opening: '+170' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '' },
  { opening: '+105' },
  { opening: '-135' },
  { opening: '-165' },
  { opening: '+135' },
  { opening: '-120' },
  { opening: '-110' },
  { opening: '-135' },
  { opening: '+105' },
  { opening: '-165' },
  { opening: '+135' },
  { opening: '-115' },
  { opening: '-115' },
  { opening: '-145' },
  { opening: '+115' },
  { opening: '+208' },
  { opening: '-263' },
  etc.
```

My desired object output is still (as example below).  So how would I get the openingBettingLine into the object associated with the fighter?

```
[
  { fighter 1: 'Khabib Nurmagomedov', openingBetLine: -333, bovadaBetLine: -365, etc. },
  { fighter 2: 'Dustin Poirier', openingBettingLine: 225, bovadaBetLine: 275, etc. },
  { fighter 3: etc.},
  { fighter 4: etc.}
]
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
**UPDATE 2 ON ORIGINAL POST** //////////////////////////

I can't get the BOVADA company's betting line to scrape.  I isolated the code to just this company below.

// BOVADA betting line array --> not working

```
rp(url)
  .then(function(html) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    const bovadaBettingLine = [];

    // parent class of fighter name
    $("div.op-item.op-spread.border-bottom.op-bovada.lv").each(
      (index, currentDiv) => {
        const bovadaBet = {
          BOVADA: JSON.parse(currentDiv.attribs["data-op-moneyline"]).fullgame
        };
        bovadaBettingLine.push(bovadaBet);
      }
    );
    console.log("bovadaBettingLine:", bovadaBettingLine);
  })
  // why isn't catch working?
  // eslint-disable-next-line handle-callback-err
  .catch(function(error) {
    // handle error
  });
```

It returns: `bovadaBettingLine: []` with nothing in it.

Below is the HTML code for that part of the website.

[image]

Comment: Did you try any `npm` package for that which converts such  things into an array

Comment: before converting anything to array, I don't know how to extract out the name and betting line values; expecting to see them in attribs key but don't see it there

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short:**

1. Select the right data with a suitable cheerio method
2. Create your own object, and put your data in there

**In Detail:**

first analyse the source code of your desired data:

```
<div class="op-matchup-team op-matchup-text op-team-top" data-op-name="{full_name:Jessica Andrade,short_name:}"><span class="op-matchup-team-text">Jessica Andrade</span></div>
```

You are trying to get the name of the fighter. So you could aim for the content of the `<span class="op-matchup-team-text">Jessica Andrade</span>` or the attribute of the parents `div` which is `data-op-name="{full_name:Jessica Andrade,short_name:}"`

Let's try the second one:

1. get all the `divs` with the desired content: `$("div.op-matchup-team.op-matchup-text.op-team-top")`
2. traverse the divs with cheerios built-in `each()` iterator
3. Within each iteration create an object with all relevant fighter parameters and push them into an `fighters` array.

see also the code comments below:

```
const rp = require("request-promise");
const url = "https://www.oddsshark.com/ufc/odds";
const cheerio = require("cheerio")
rp(url)
    .then(function (html) {

    const $ = cheerio.load(html)


    const fighters = [];
    $("div.op-matchup-team.op-matchup-text.op-team-top")
        .each((index, currentDiv) => {
            const fighter = {
                name: JSON.parse(currentDiv.attribs["data-op-name"]).full_name,
                //There is no direct selector for the rows of the second column based on the first one.
                //So you need to select all rows of the second column as you did, and then use the current index
                //to get the right row. Put the selected data into your "basket" the fighter object. Done.
                openingBetLine: JSON.parse($("div.op-item.op-spread.op-opening")[index].attribs["data-op-moneyline"]).fullgame
                // go on the same way with the other rows that you need.
            }

            fighters.push(fighter)
        })

    console.log(fighters)


    }).catch(function (error) {
     //error catch does work, you just need to print it out to see it
     console.log(error)
    });
```

will give you:

```
[{ name: 'Jessica Andrade',
openingBetLine: '-200'},...]
```

Comment: please see my edited question with updates at the bottom;  using Henk's methodology i'm able to scrape the betting line, but I'm a noob at this and don't know how to get the fighter name and betting lines on the same object.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: thank you so much, that worked!  I'm able to scrape every betting line except bovada for some reason.  please see update 2 section in my code for details

Comment: @PineNuts0 check your selectors, and check if `$("div.op-item.op-spread.border-bottom.op-bovada.lv")`is giving you the right data to traverse.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call get() to turn the cheerio object into an array:

```
let teamData = $('.op-matchup-wrapper').map((i, div) => ({
  time: $(div).find('.op-matchup-time').text(),
  teams: $(div).find('.op-matchup-team-text').map((i, t) => $(t).text()).get()
})).get()
```

Those betting lines are outside of the teams area so you would need to get them separately and merge them somehow.